# Read *.bok and *.mdb files in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, fonts, arabic

I have used Windows to read an Arabic book (*.mdb & *.bok) by Maktaba Shamela.

Now I want to use Ubuntu 12.04 to read *.bok & *.mdb files. I tried to install Maktaba Shamela with Wine, but the Arabic font was not shown.

I tried to install thwab (not Thawab) to read my Arabic book (*.bok), but I could not install it. Now I want to install Maktabah Al-Miftah, but to read *.bok, I need to import the (.mfth) file from a Shamela file (.bok) by using AccessDump.py and it depends on gambas3-gb-db-sqlite3.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try [**Maktaba El-Kirtasse**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/elkirtasse/) or **Maktabah Al-Miftah 3.1** (Ubuntu 12.10). Both can import `.bok` file automatically.

If you use **Maktabah Al-Miftah 3.0** (Ubuntu 12.04), you need to import `.bok` manually. Download `AccessDump.py` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/miftah/files/miftah/). Run this command in terminal after you entered the `AccessDump.py` folder:

```
MDB_JET3_CHARSET="cp1256" python ./AccessDump.py filename.bok | sqlite3 filename.mfth
```

Then you may open the `.mfth` file with **Maktabah Al-Miftah 3.0**.