# I want to read my *.bok in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, arabic

I have files with extension **.bok** from Shamela file.
They contain Arabic text. 
What can I do to read **.bok** files in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Is there an application to open them?

=== UPDATED Tue 18 Oct 2016 ===

I have followed this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257060/i-want-to-read-my-bok-and-mdb-in-ubuntu-12-04) but it doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04.

`.bok` files can be opened by Maktaba El-Kirtasse & Maktabah Al-Miftah but they are not displayed correctly.

They look like this:

أچأ‘أ‌ أ‡أ،أƒأ،أ‌ أƒ - أ‡أ،أچأ³أ‘أ؛أ‌أµ أ‡أ،أƒأ¦أ¸أ³أ،أµ أ£أ¶أ¤أ³ أ‡أ،أچأµأ‘أµأ¦أ‌أ¶ أ‡أ،أ¥أ¶أŒأ³أ‡أ†أ¶أ­أ¸أ³أ‰أ¶ (أ£أ„أ¤أ‹أ‰) أ¦أ³أٹأµأ‘أ؛أ“أ³أ£أµ أڑأ³أ­أ؛أ¤أ‡أ° أ•أ³أ›أ¶أ­أ‘أ³أ‰أ° (أپ) أ¦أ³أ­أ³أٹأ³أڑأ³أ­أ¸أ³أ¤أµ أ¤أ³أ¦أ؛أڑأ³أ‡أ¤أ

[this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9clcdsyq8s90mua/%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%AD%20%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A1.bok?dl=0) is an example `.bok` file

Comment: Can you give a sample of the file?

Comment: i have followed this [guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257060/i-want-to-read-my-bok-and-mdb-in-ubuntu-12-04) but not work in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 

file `.bok` can be opened by Maktaba El-Kirtasse & Maktabah Al-Miftah but not display correctly.

appear like these :

أچأ‘أ‌ أ‡أ،أƒأ،أ‌
أƒ - أ‡أ،أچأ³أ‘أ؛أ‌أµ أ‡أ،أƒأ¦أ¸أ³أ،أµ أ£أ¶أ¤أ³ أ‡أ،أچأµأ‘أµأ¦أ‌أ¶ أ‡أ،أ¥أ¶أŒأ³أ‡أ†أ¶أ­أ¸أ³أ‰أ¶ (أ£أ„أ¤أ‹أ‰) أ¦أ³أٹأµأ‘أ؛أ“أ³أ£أµ أڑأ³أ­أ؛أ¤أ‡أ° أ•أ³أ›أ¶أ­أ‘أ³أ‰أ° (أپ) أ¦أ³أ­أ³أٹأ³أڑأ³أ­أ¸أ³أ¤أµ أ¤أ³أ¦أ؛أڑأ³أ‡أ¤أ

Comment: @Anwar [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9clcdsyq8s90mua/%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%AD%20%D9%85%D8%AA%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A1.bok?dl=0) is example file `.bok`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some apps like 
**Maktabah Al-Miftah**, **Maktaba El-Kirtasse**, **Xbook**, **Thawab**, but Only **Thawab** that renders Arabic words correctly in Ubuntu 16.04

Now, I used **Thawab** for open file with extension `.bok` In Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thawab
```

[image: Thawab]

Answer (score 0):

From the Description page of **Maktabah Al-Miftah** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/miftah):

> This application is not compatible with Ubuntu 15.10 and up.

I use **Maktabah Al-Miftah** in Ubuntu 15.04 and it renders Arabic words correctly.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation? Also, 15.04 is EOL, so I suggest using 14.04, since using obsolete versions is insecure and likely to cause package-management problems