# How can I convert .BOK file to .PDF file in Ubuntu?

Tags: pdf, convert, conversion

How can I convert .BOK file to .PDF file? I searched enough but I only found solutions that work on Windows, but none for Ubuntu. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: You could use an online converter, here an example: http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf . I assume your file is something like an ebook-file and I haven't tried that.

Comment: Related : https://askubuntu.com/questions/836775/i-want-to-read-my-bok-in-ubuntu-16-04/873637

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the simplest solution will be to print .bok to .pdf using virtual printer.

`sudo apt-get install cups-pdf` will allow you to do so.

Now you have a new printer called "PDF". When you print with it, the .pdf file will be saved to `~/PDF`.

Comment: But where do I find that printer? (I don't have a reader for those .BOK files)

Comment: Is there a command I can type in the terminal that will trigger the print command?

Comment: As you have no reader, you cannot print .BOK files. The only way to print/convert .BOK files seems to be running a windows converter program in WINE.

Comment: Combine this with `apt-get install thawab`. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/873637/491330).